# Change state from dynamically created child component - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, dom-events, setstate

In this app, you can change the football matches score by clicking the `GOAL` button of a particular game. The problem is that my matches are saved in the state and I render them with the `map` method and I can't use setState dynamically for each match.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import Match from './components/Match';

import './App.css';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      games: [
        {
          home: {
            team: "Bruges",
            score: 0
          },
          guests: {
            team: "Real Madrid",
            score: 0
          }
        },
        {
          home: {
            team: "Atletico Madrid",
            score: 0
          },
          guests: {
            team: "Lokomotiv",
            score: 0
          }
        }
      ]
    };

    this.goal = this.goal.bind(this);
  };

  goal(parent) {
    let rand = Math.round(Math.random());

    if(rand) {
      this.setState((prevstate) => ({parent:  prevstate.parent.home.score + 1}))
    } else {
      this.setState((prevstate) => ({parent: prevstate.parent.guests.score + 1}))
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.games.map((item, index) => {
          return (<Match 
            key={index}

            home={item.home.team}
            homeScore={item.home.score}

            guests={item.guests.team}       
            guestsScore={item.guests.score}

            goal={() => this.goal(item)}
          />);
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

**Match.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import '../App.css'

const Match = props => {
    return(
    <div className="match-container">
        <span className="name-container">{props.home} </span>
        <span className="score-container">{props.homeScore}</span>

        <button onClick={props.goal}>GOAL</button>

        <span className="score-container">{props.guestsScore} </span>
        <span className="name-container">{props.guests} </span>
    </div>
    );
}

export default Match;
```

**[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-night-bh0ct?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)**

I think my problem is in the `goal` method because I don't think that I can pass an argument and use it in `setState`.

I didn't find an answer related to this particular problem.

Comment: you want to update clicked button value?

Comment: @VahidAkhtar I want to update homeScore or guestScore

Comment: Does games have to be an array? It would be so much simpler if it was an object where each game had a unique key. Can you change the implementation or do you have to use an array?

Comment: @JoshPittman yeah, I need to use array in this case :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to update an array as if it were an object. The fact is that you have set games as an array in state. Here is how you update it:

```
goal(parent) {
    let rand = Math.round(Math.random());
    const { games } = this.state;
    const index = games.findIndex(element => element === parent);
    const newGames = [...games];
    if (rand) {
      newGames[index].home.score = newGames[index].home.score + 1;
    } else {
      newGames[index].guests.score = newGames[index].guests.score + 1;
    }
    this.setState({ games: newGames });
  }
```

Here is a working demo https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-margulis-n0ch1

Comment: So if I understand right, you distract the state and take only `games` array. Then you take the index from the index of the button that was clicked, then again take the `games` array and assign it to the `newGames`, change it with the condition and setting as a state?

Comment: Yes, you should never mutate state. If you want to make a change you create a copy of the bit you want to change, update it, and then save the updated version. This has nothing to do with my response, this is just react best practices https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and further explanation. That was a totally satisfying answer!!!